# Migrating sitecollection from SharePoint 2007 to 2010

Tags: migration

I have a webapplication containing many sitecollections in SharePoint 2007 , I specifically want to migrate only a single sitecollection from 2007 to Sharepoint 2010  . Whats the best way to do it ?

1) Can I do it without migrating content database from 2007 to 2010 as I only require a single sitecollection to be moved ?

2) Can I use SPobjectmodel using SPExportSettings/SPImportSettings ... to migrate my sitecollection ?

Thanks for replying...

Answer (score 5):

No, import/export can only be done to farms of the same version.

You could

- Add a new content database to your 2007 web application
- move the single site collection to the new database
- Run pre upgrade check
- Attach and run Test-SPContentDatabase on the 2010 server
- Then upgrade with Upgrade-SPContentDatabase
- Then move the site collection from the upgraded content database to your normal 2010 content db.

The key step is the upgrade, as it converts the schema from v3 to v4

Comment: That's what I was going to suggest too, split the 2007 site collection into it's own content DB and do a DB attach upgrade on that.

Comment: my words again. GJ djeeg

Comment: Can't I write a code utility for doing this , using SharePoint APIs.., Client wants a UI kind of thing where he can select a sitecollection from dropdown and can click on Upgrade button which should perform the task of migration from 2007 to 2010.

Comment: @All : I googled a lot for this and found out that there is a way to do this . U can change SystemData.xml found in .cmp file generated through Sharepoint Export utility with the new version of sharepoint(14.0.0.0) and then can import .cmp file to 2010...This way u can import 2007 sitecollection to 2010..are there any pros and cons in doing this ...

Answer (score 0):

A slightly simpler approach to consider is to go the [unattached content database](http://archive.feedblitz.com/714474/~3905799) route (still needs to upgrade the DB schema). You can then export the required content using the granular backup tools and import the content using Powershell, or backup the site collection.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add that we have a tool MetaVis Migrator for SharePoint that can help you to copy site collections. You can copy there the whole site collections or you can copy granularly individual sites, lists, libraries, content types, fields, individual items and documents with versions and metadata, groups, users and permissions, WEB Part Pages with WEB Parts, list views, term stores with term sets, certain look and feel and navigation settings and some SharePoint Designer customizations. It can copy data from SharePoint 2003, 2007 or 2010 sites, from file systems and Exchange public folders, preserves created and modified times and users, looks like Windows Explorer with drag and drop and copy / paste capabilities.

We have 15 days free trial. If you have Office 365 account you can download the product and give it a try.  http://www.metavistech.com

Let us know whether you liked it.

Thank you,
Mark